# GAE Vs AWS 2012

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, scalability, porting

Is GAE is a good option for the backend when compared with AWS? The information found mainly discusses the issues that GAE has resolved as of today. The mobile application under consideration deals with the images. Sharing and editing of images simultaneously with multiple users.

I am mainly concerned with the Scalability & flexibility in the implementation. The robust & compability layer, Storage and data analysis (analysis (identifying the patterns)of the data stored).

AWS lets use the popular open source technologies & tools and has a granular pricing. GAE is good to get to market really fast, no administration pain, and a free quota.

Can you please point out some important pros & cons that I must consider before taking the decision.

Answer (score 3):

I think that GAE is good for its fast startup and for proof of concept. It is really simple and cheaper to begin with, but it locks you in to google.

If your idea works well and it becomes popular you can rewrite it using open source technology in future.

Comment: You can run your gae code on appscale, http://code.google.com/p/appscale/ so you are not really locked in even from the start.

Comment: @Rekby, I think your answer is pretty good. I agree 100%. Paul C, I think it's not the same to plan and run your own infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I have 25 GB appengine DB. Every 1-10 minutes I add record.
It costs $2.5 per week.

But originally it was more expensive to upload then I ever expected. 
My upload script was uploading chunks 500 records per request.

Requests were ending in 10-15 seconds but logs showed datastore time much more like 5 minutes vs 15 real seconds!
Also upload servlet was waiting 99% of time doing nothing and I had to pay for that as well.

It took days to upload 15 GB of indexed data.

AppEngine has certain pricing risks

Comment: It isn't only pricing. If you don't pay $500/month for premiun account you can't send derect question in support. I have it problem with my app. For example some days ago my production app start work much (about 10-15 time - 1500-2500ms in production app instead 13-100ms in test app with same code and near same data (result of queries are identical) ) slower than my test app. I send production issue and haven't answer, send question to stackoverflow (to official tag for support) some days ago and I don't have answer or solve problem. I can't do anything with it - only wait.

Comment: I like GAE but go out as soon as possible, becouse I very small for google and it don't solve problems with my apps and don't answer to me.

Comment: Network latency. You do not know where your instance and where is your data. In AWS you can keep it in same region.

Comment: May be, but it is problem of google. GAE hide internal structure from me - it good. But google isn't solve problem if it is problem with 1 application. I don't want think about latency in GAE if I can't change it. In peak of problem few days it request work in production about 10-30 SECONDS instead of 13-100 ms.

Comment: Before it I have other case usage google - I wrote customer support interface in GAE. It very often add and delete blobstores (some thouthands per day). When I delete blobstore google don't delete some index data. I send production issue in 01.02.2012 it was accepted but don't solved - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6849

Answer (score 0):

GAE is essentially for "throw-away" proof of concepts or "very very small" applications.  I say this because, I would not invest is a large amount of money into a completely vendor locked system...Other people might but I wouldn't take that kind of risk since I'd be at Google's whim on their availability and pricing.

So if you have a large project or product, you're probably better off using EC2 since all it's providing is the infrastructure...there's no code requirements imposed on you.

That being said, if I had a small project I wanted to toss on the web for my friends, I'd definitely take advantage of GAE's free tier.

I think the biggest difference is that, in a general sense, EC2 hosts servers whereas GAE hosts code. If you're building a system where you're going to want to do things like tail logs, have cron jobs managed by a sys admin, use open source tools like rsync and have fine grained control over OS and configuration or co-locate services on one box, then EC2 is very compelling.

GAE is "upload your app and it works".  Very cool in its own right but personally I'd rather deal with VMs in EC2 because it's a more natural dynamic for systems development for me at least.